# My Rock Paper Scissors program in jQuery is only returning the result when it is a tie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the link to the pen on CodePen where I made this: http://codepen.io/PartTimeCoder/pen/KzQQvM?editors=0010

My Javascript, the problem must be in the if commands at the bottom of the $("img").click() function:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var user;
    user = this.id;

    var computer = Math.random();

    if (computer <= 0.33) {
        computer = "Rock"
    } else if (computer <= 0.67) {
        computer = "Scissors"
    } else {
        computer = "Paper"
    }

    $(".cpu").html("The computer chose - " + computer);
    $(".you").html("You chose - " + user);
    $(".result").html("");

    if (computer == user) {
        $(".result").html("It's a tie!");
    }
    if (user == "paper") {
        if (computer == "rock") {
            $(".result").html("You win!");
        } else {
            $(".result").html("You lose!");
        }
    }

    if (user == "rock") {
        if (computer == "scissors") {
            $(".result").html("You win!");
        } else {
            $(".result").html("You lose!");
        }
    }

    if (user == "scissors") {
        if (computer == "paper") {
            $(".result").html("You win!");
        } else {
            $(".result").html("You lose!");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your id's are in caps case, but you are trying to match lower case. Change either the code or the markup.

For example, the id for rock is `Rock`, but your logic tries to match `user == 'rock'`. If you changed the id to `rock`, your code should work. You'll need to repeat this for each id ie rock, paper and scissors.

Comment: Oh, I should've seen that thanks!

Comment: @AnishKasam: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The strings are case-sensitive. `"Scissors" != "scissors"`.

Here it is again with correction and also a simpler IF()

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var user;
    user = this.id;

    var computer = Math.random();

    if (computer <= 1/3) {
        computer = "Rock"
    } else if (computer <= 2/3) {
        computer = "Scissors"
    } else {
        computer = "Paper"
    }

    $(".cpu").html("The computer chose - " + computer);
    $(".you").html("You chose - " + user);

    var result = '';

    if (computer == user) {
        result = "It's a tie!";
    } else if (user == "Paper" &&  computer == "Rock") {
        result = "You win!";
    } else if (user == "Rock" && computer == "Scissors") {
        result = "You win!";
    } else if (user == "Scissors" && computer == "Paper") {
        result = "You win!";
    } else {
        result = "You lose!";
    }

    $(".result").html(result);
});
```